# Using pywin32 to get a list of the source, date/time, and messages for all error entries to the event log in the past 3 months

Tags: python, error-handling, pywin32, event-log

Edit; 
My original post was too vague regarding what my problem was, so after working on my assignment for some time I've adjusted/fixed most of my code. However, I'm still having trouble getting it to work. Now when I run the script from the cmd prompt I get this message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PythonScriptsR2/autoadmin_a1_errors.py", line 45, in <module>
    log_handle_three = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(computer,log_type_three)
pywintypes.error: (1722, 'OpenEventLogW', 'The RPC server is 
unavailable.')
```

Here is what my current code looks like
(I wrote some comments on and around line 45 so it's easier to find);

```
import win32evtlog
import win32evtlogutil
import win32security
import win32con
import time
import winerror
import re
import string
import sys
import traceback

####################################################################
# All error entries for the last 3 months
########
#set date format
def date2sec(self,evt_date):
    '''
    convert '12/23/99 15:54:09' to seconds
    print '333333',evt_date
    '''
    regexp=re.compile('(.*)\\s(.*)')
    reg_result=regexp.search(evt_date)
    date = reg.result.group(1)
    time = reg_result.group(2)
    (mon,day,yr) = map(lambda x: sring.atoi(x),string.split(date,'/'))
    (hr,min,sec) = map(lambda x: sring.atoi(x),string.split(time,':'))
    tup = [yr,mon,day,hr,min,sec,0,0,0]
    sec = time.mktime(tup)
    return sec
################
#Initialize variables
flags_three=win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|\
            win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ

    #Dictionary to convert event type into human readable form
evt_dict={win32con.EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE:'EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE',\
          win32con.EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS:'EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS',\
          win32con.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE:'EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE',\
          win32con.EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE:'EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE',\
          win32con.EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE:'EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE'}

computer='bedrock'
log_type_three='System'
begin_sec=time.time()
begin_time=time.strftime('%H:%M:%S ',time.localtime(begin_sec))
############                 \/ Line 45 \/                   #############
log_handle_three=win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(computer,log_type_three) #line45
############                 /\ Line 45 /\                   #############
################
#Open the Event Log
print(log_type_three,' error events found from the last three months 
since:',begin_time)
try:
    ev_ents=1
    while ev_ents:
        ev_ents=win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(log_handle_three,flags_three, 0)
        for ev_obj in ev_ents:
#################
            #check if  the event is recent enough
            #checking data from the last three months
            date = ev_ent.TimeGenerated.Format()
            time = ev_ent.TimeGenerated.Format()
            seconds = date2sec(date)
            if seconds < begin_sec-7862400: break
#################
            #if the data is recent enough/from the correct time frame, 
            #print it  
            source=str(ev_obj.SourceName)
            message=str(win32evtlogutil.SafeFormatMessage(ev_obj,\ 
                                                          logtype))
            record = str(ev_obj.RecordNumber)
            print(string.join((record,source,date,\
                               time,message[0:15]),':'))
        if seconds < begin_sec-7862400: break #You need to get out of 
                                              #the while loop as well
        win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(log_handle_three)
except:
    print(traceback.print_exc(sys.exc_info()))
```

So right now my questions are, what does this error message mean, why am I getting this error message, and what are some things I could do to try and fix it.

I think he may want us to use windows powershell to call the script, however, when I did this I got the same error message as I did at the cmd prompt so I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: "I'm running into problems with the code I use to specify the date that the event log should start returning info from." What problem is that?  Also, do we need all of this code to help you on a date problem?

Comment: I understand that my post isn't written very well and is somewhat confusing, and I'd like to apologize for that. but to be honest I was having trouble finding possible solutions to the problem my teacher gave me so I thought I might post what I had so far and see if anyone could give me ideas as to what I might be able to try. -----to give some context, we are working with the pywin32 module in my class and my teacher uses the 'Socratic teaching method' basically meaning he doesn't give lectures or answers questions but instead expects us to figure it out ourselves

Comment: so to rephrase my question, I am trying to read the event log and print all of the errors that were recorded for the past three months. including the source of the error, the date of the error, and the error message itself.

Comment: please let me know if my question makes any sense or if there is anything confusing about my wording because part of my problem is that I'm having trouble figuring out what my question is or needs to be so that I can try and properly address it

Comment: What do you actually need help with though?  is the code you have returning an error message?

Comment: I just edited my entire post so hopefully my question(s) are more clear now

Comment: A search online of error code `1722` shows that it may be related to permissions. Since you are attempting to get the log files, I think that makes sense. Can you try running your script as `administrator`?

Comment: Info here might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287121/reading-windows-event-log-in-python-using-pywin32-win32evtlog-module

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I think it's probably trying to access "bedrock" using the network stack instead of just grabbing it from the local machine. I would make sure that "bedrock" is the actual computer name that you get when you execute "hostname" from the CLI.

I ran into a similar issue using a computer name of "localhost" where it didn't work in certain environments with the same error. Changing that value to the actual local computer name resolved the problem for me.