# How to log file browser actions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I log file browser actions with python?

I want to log user interaction with the file explorer on windows.
Looking for interactions like opening new folders, clicking files, opening files.

Is this the best way to interact with the filebrowser?
This is what I have now:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time, win32process, win32gui

def active_explorer_folder():
    active_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) #-- This produces a list of PIDs active window relates to

    clsid = '{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}' #-- Valid for IE as well!
    shellwindows = win32.DispatchEx(clsid)

    for window in range(shellwindows.Count):
        current_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(shellwindows[window].Hwnd)
        if current_pid == active_pid: #-- If pid matches with active PIDs
            return shellwindows[window].LocationURL

while True:
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(active_explorer_folder())
```

Comment: On the Mac I think it's called the Finder. Regardless, I don't think there's a way to do what you want (with Python anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the `filecmp` library here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html

There are actually already several approaches availible.

`watchdog` could also be intresting for you: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

`win32 evtlog` http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32evtlog.html

a question related to your's: [Reading windows event log in Python using pywin32 (win32evtlog module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287121/reading-windows-event-log-in-python-using-pywin32-win32evtlog-module)

Comment: If im not wrong these options look for file creation and editing. I am mainly interested in the interaction with the file explorer. So even when no files has been created or changed, just the action of opening a browser or opening a file.

Comment: You may use the `Change File Modification Time` /  `File Access Time` or check for windows the `win32` api

Comment: Ah sounds better, something like this? http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyIExplorerBrowserEvents.html

Comment: Yes possibly. I think you have to use several approaches to meet your needs. But with the ones I posted you'll probably find solutions regarding your task.

Comment: Thanks for your direction, got the basics working! Probably another approach will work more efficient. Now I have to run a loop insead of printing out signals directly from the file browser. Updated the main post. (Post was closed, not sure how to react to that so did it this way)