# The system cannot find the file specified error in python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, get-winevent

i want to run following power-shell command using python script:

```
timedetail = subprocess.check_output('powershell.exe Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational  | Where { ($_.ID -eq "25" -or  $_.ID -eq "21") -and ($_.TimeCreated -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-2))} |Select TimeCreated , Message | sort-Object -Property TimeCreated -Unique | Format-List', startupinfo=st_inf,shell=False,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).decode('ANSI').strip().splitlines()
```

but this is not working with python code this is displaying an error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

anyone can help how to run powershell command using python code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want to read events from the Windows event Log, did you try the `win32evtlog` module from `pywin32`? (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287121/reading-windows-event-log-in-python-using-pywin32-win32evtlog-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `run` instead of `check_output`. `run` [has been added in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) and it is recommended to use it prior to `call`, `check_call` or `check_output`. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40697622/10095043).

`run` returns a `CompletedProcess` that is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess).

Here is an updated version of your script:

```py
import subprocess


def run_powershell_command(command):
    completed = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", command], capture_output=True)
    return completed


get_logs_command = 'Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational  | Where { ($_.ID -eq "25" -or  $_.ID -eq "21") -and ($_.TimeCreated -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-2))} |Select TimeCreated , Message | sort-Object -Property TimeCreated -Unique | Format-List'
result = run_powershell_command(get_logs_command)

for line in result.stdout.splitlines():
    print(line)
```